# How do I make an Android background thread?

Tags: android

I have an Android application that connects to a database. I would like to write a background thread to continuously update data from the database, using httpclient, and still be able to update the UI displaying the most recent data, let's say, every 1/2 second. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html - this is exactly what you need.

Comment: AsyncTask is a "one-time-only" thread - once it finishes the AsyncTask dies - you will need to run it inside a while loop and create a new AsyncTask. I'd recommend using Handler.postDelayed or TimerTask instead...

Comment: Not necessarily.  AsyncTask will run for as long as you need it.  You can have the loop in its `doInBackground` method, which would extract the data and assign it to local variable.  In `updateProgress`` you'll provide that data.  `doInBackgroun` loop will keep running until you no longer need it.  Creating `AsyncTask`s in a loop is a rather bad idea.

Comment: Well you can't supply more params than what it takes in the doInBackground method. So you can supply a number of urls for instance in the params, but after that the AsyncTask can't be used for anything and a new would have to be created.
And yeah using the AsyncTask in a loop is a bad idea, that was what I was hinting at - I guess it wasn't that clear ;)
Handler.postDelayed with an interval of 500 ms would be smoother in my opinion.

Comment: @Darwind: Fist, you can pass any object into AsyncTask - and that object `Object[]`, which means you can pass any amount of any data into it.  Second, you can change the URL that an existing AsyncTask is using: create a member variable in your subclass, assign it initially when you create the instance; provide a setter method (synchronize on the var) and use that variable for connection in `doInBackground`.  When you need to change URL, just call the setter with the new URL.  On the next iteration of internal loop in `doInBackground` the new url will be used.

Comment: @Merlin: what about concurrency?  I'm not sure I understand your point.

Comment: accessing the database on separate threads.  ps Editing your answer may be more valuable than giant comments ;)

Comment: His database is remote - he wants to use HttpClient to connect to remote something where the DB is, so concurrency here isn't a problem.

Comment: @AleksG: I see your point I just don't see how it's the best solution. You would create a lot of unnecessary code handling the repeating of the updating from the database.
Isn't it crossthreading (even though it's safe because you synchronized the var) if you supply a new url by using a setter on the AsyncTask or is the var not part of the AsyncTask?
I'm not only here for answering questions - I'm here to learn as well, that's why I ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the class `AsyncTask` , refer this tutorials to know more about it :) :

http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/182/show-progressbar-while-downloading-image-using-asynctask-in-android/ ,

[AsyncTask Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: @StealthRabbi : you're right, i've updated links, check them now :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of data!

If you are displaying and then inserting the same data into the database then AsyncTask will work. However, if you are planning to access your database from the UI at the same time as inserting data from online then you will run into concurrency issues.

I had to use a content provider to provide concurrent access to the database.  The beauty of that was that I could then use a syncadapter to handle the data retrival without affecting the UI.